# Table in Row. How to show each value as percentage of total row of the table

Tags: r

I'm trying to show each value in a percentage of its total row value.

```
ClientFeedbackQuant <- cut(MR_Data$ClientFeedbackScore, quantile(MR_Data$ClientFeedbackScore, c(0,.20,.4,.6,.8,1)) ,include.lowest = TRUE)

table1 <- table(MR_Data$Division , ClientFeedbackQuant)
table1
```

> ```
>            [11,72] (72,84.2] (84.2,91] (91,97] (97,100]
>   Atlanta       44         9         2       1        0
>   Denver        22        56        24      20        9
>   Mobile        61        36        31      14       38
>   Portland       0        20        75      82       75
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `prop.table`

```
prop.table(table1, 1)
```

Comment: wow. it worked. How did you know? I was going to fix the format of my question.